# C language tokenizer output for static integer array

Tags: lexical-analysis

Unable to find out how the C-language lexical analyzer would tokenize the declaration of a static array. Say, int i[3]= {1,2,3};

The lexical analyzer would need to differentiate between just an integer identifier i, and a static array of size 3.

Am confused how the lexical analyzer would tokenize.

Tried Holub's book, among others, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: "The lexical analyzer would need to differentiate between just an integer identifier i, and a static array of size 3.": sorry, I have no idea what you try to express.

Comment: IMO, the tokens are `|int|i|[|3|]|=|{|1|,|2|,|3|}|;|`. Keyword, identifier, separator, literal constant... If this can help you, the text `3{int,,i 2 3];}[=` would yield the same tokens. The tokens are (very simple) regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my answer I assume you are acquainted with formal grammars, especially, the Backus Naur form.

The lexical analyzer, alone, could never state the sentence you provided actually belongs to C.
Telling whether it belongs or not to the language, is a joint duty of the lexical and syntactical analyzers.

On one hand, the purpose of the lexer is telling whether a given sequence of characters corresponds to some keyword or pattern. On the other hand, the purpose of the syntactical analyzer is telling whether a sequence of symbols and characters is admitted by the grammar.

A simple grammar $\mathcal{G}$ (unrelated to the C language) generating this kind of construct could be:

- $S \rightarrow T \text{ } id \text{ } A = \{ L \}$
- $A \rightarrow [ L ] $
- $L \rightarrow num \text{ } |\text{ } LL $
- $LL \rightarrow LL\text{ },\text{ } num\text{ }|\text{ } num$
- $T \rightarrow int\text{ } |\text{ } float\text{ } | \text{ }double$

(Assuming `id` corresponds to the lexical language of ids, etc.)

The lexer would tokenize the string generating 14 tokens, that is:

- (`int`, INT)
- (`i`, ID)
- (`[`, LBRACKET)
- (`3`, INTEGER)
- (`]`, RBRACKET)
- (`=`, ASSIGN)
- (`{`, LCURLY)
- (`1`, INTEGER)
- (`,`, COMMA)
- (`2`, INTEGER)
- (`,`, COMMA)
- (`3`, INTEGER)
- (`}`, RCURLY)
- (`;`, COLON).
  (For suitable constants INT, INTEGER, ID, COMMA, etc.)

At parse time the parse would tell the sentence belongs to the language, and could distinguish the meaning of each lexem by its left and right context (that precedes and follows it.)

I hope this explanation will help.